# Unit testing Tool for Sybase database

Tags: unit-testing, sybase

Do we have any tools to unit testing Sybase databases around?

i am not able to find one in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks

i am looking out for a tool that can allow me to unit test Stored procedure.Something like wee do with [utPLSQL](http://utplsql.sourceforge.net/).This tool will be used by Database guys to unit test.

Comment: Please add more information, otherwise, nobody can help you.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you want to test? The correctness of Sybase itself or some stored procedures you've written that run in Sybase? If the latter, then you could use JUnit to execute the stored procedures via JDBC (I'm assuming based on your username that Java is a language you're comfortable with).

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking in to [SqlUnit](http://sqlunit.sourceforge.net/) for xUnit level testing of stored procedures and such.  It seems promising.  I'm installing and fiddling with it now.

Answer (score -1):

Please try to use AnyDbTest first, (www.anydbtest.com). I think it is the very tool you are finding. even through the AnyDbTest is not support sybase at this moment.  We are working to support Sybase these days.

Comment: www.anydbtest.com doesn't even exist